# Finding Difference between two dates in Java

Tags: java, date, datediff, jformattedtextfield

I'm using two `JFormattedTextFields` in Java for Date in my `JFrame`. I formatted them in format `(DD/MM/YYYY)`.

How can i find difference between them in days?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2013, 12, 20, 0, 0);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2013, 12, 23, 0, 0);
Days.daysBetween(date1, date2).getDays(); // Will return 3 
//since date2 is 3 days after date1
```

Comment: Cool, he just improved his copy paste skills. Also, he wants to parse some dates, so your answer is incomplete.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea I knot that this answer is not full, it is intentional. OP will have to do his portion of work by reading docs or tutorials to convert Date to DateTime (which is not hard).

Answer (score 0):

Parse the dates, use Calendar standard class or Joda Time library to compare the dates.